# Serialport in a separate QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I'd like to insert the serial port in a separate QThread, but the application crashes. I wrote the following C++ classes

**Worker.h**

```
 class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void finished();
    void error(QString err);

public slots:
    void process();

};

class WorkerInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkerInterface(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~WorkerInterface();

    serialport *readSerialPort();

signals:
    void threadStoppedChanged();

public slots:
    void errorString(QString errorMsg);
    void stopThread();

private:
    QThread m_thread;
    serialPort *m_serial;
};

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Worker::process()
{

    emit finished();
}
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
WorkerInterface::WorkerInterface(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_thread(this)
{
    serialPort::serialPortMaster = new serialPort(nullptr);
    m_serial = serialPort::serialPortMaster;
    serialPort::serialPortMaster->moveToThread(&m_thread);
    connect(&m_thread, SIGNAL(started()),serialPort::serialPortMaster, SLOT(Init()));
    m_thread.start();

}

WorkerInterface::~WorkerInterface()
{
    m_thread.quit();
    m_thread.wait(1000);
    if (!m_thread.isFinished())
        m_thread.terminate();

}

void WorkerInterface::errorString(QString errorMsg)
{
    qDebug() << "error" << errorMsg;
}

void WorkerInterface::stopThread()
{
    m_thread.quit();
    m_thread.wait(1000);
    if (!m_thread.isFinished())
        m_thread.terminate();

    emit threadStoppedChanged();
}

serialPort* WorkerInterface::readSerialPort()
{
    return(m_serialPort);
}
```

**In the main.cpp I wrote the following code:**

```
WorkerInterface workerInterface;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("newserial", workerInterface.readSerialPort());

QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Pages/Content/Qml/main.qml")));

QObject *qmlObject = component.create();
```

When the code arrives at the last instruction in main.cpp, the application crashes and in the QT creator console there is the following messages:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0xee18c0), parent's thread is QThread(0xc8d8b0), current thread is QThread(0x7fffffffdc60)

QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0xee18c0), parent's thread is QThread(0xc8d8b0), current thread is QThread(0x7fffffffdc60)
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to serialPort(0xee1710) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x7fffffffdc30.
```

Could someone help me to solve the crash?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps off topic but... why do you feel the need to create a new thread to manage the `QSerialPort`?

Comment: I do not have time to explain all mistakes done here. Here is a short list of mistakes: global variable (hidden in strange way), thread owned by object which is moved to thread, missing code with actual reading. In fact I don't see a reason to use threads here. I know they are fancy and look like a golden solution for all performance issues, but they are hard to master and even harder to maintain when you do not know what are you doing.

Comment: Dear @Marek, thanks for your answer. I need to insert the serial port into a different thread to increase its performance, because when I change page on the user interface, the serial port stops working for a moment. I never used multithreading and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @MarekR sorry I wrote a different name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have device which responds with text, the best and simplest way to do it is something like this:

```
class IODevLineReader
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IODevLineReader(QObject *parent);

public signals:
    void lineWasReceived(const QString &line);

public slots:
    void onReadyRead() {
        QIODevice *dev = qobject_cast<QIODevice *>(sender());
        while (dev && dev->canReadLine()) {
            auto lineBytes = dev->readLine();
            emit lineWasReceived(lineBytes);
        }
    }
};
```

Just connect `QSerialPort::readyRead()` to `IODevLineReader::onReadyRead()` and connect some slot to `IODevLineReader::lineWasReceived()` signal and you are done without use of threads.

And if you still insist to use thread, just use same object tree and move it to specified thread.